# Please make [ics] a synonym for [4.0-ice-cream-sandwich]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Lots of people are abbreviating Ice Cream Sandwich as "ics". I've fixed about a half-dozen questions today.

Please make [ics](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ics) a synonym of [4.0-ice-cream-sandwich](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4.0-ice-cream-sandwich).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, I actually think I tried to suggest this a few weeks back but I didn't meet the criteria for suggesting the synonym at the time (and then forgot about it). In any case, agreed and done.

Comment: Suggesting synonyms is pretty useles without a massive user base, too few people have the rep in the tag (nevermind actually look at the synonym page regularly).  Meta is the best bet for these.

Comment: @MatthewRead: I don't even know why I tried to do it that way, honestly. I've made other synonym requests here in the past instead. Maybe I was just trying to earn the badge, haha